# multiclassmetrics Import error in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, python-2.6

In Spark, I import `MultiClassMetrics` using this command `from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics` but get below error:

```
ImportError: No module named evaluation
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: If you're on a Spark version < 1.4 then that module is not available and hence your error.

Comment: Thanks my problem solved.